# This is a number guessing game the num_check function works just fine the first time but won't run any second attempts. Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, function

```
import random

# Define function - Number Generator
def num_gen():

    num = random.randrange(1, 101)
    return num

# Define function - Number Check
def num_check(x, y):

    result = ''
    if x > y:
        result = 'high'
    elif x < y:
        result = 'low'
    else:
        result = 'correct'
    return result

# Call - Number Generator
num = num_gen()

# Input - Guess
guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))

att = 1

# Process - Guess and Display Result
result = num_check(guess, num)

if result == 'high':

    guess = int(input('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
    att += 1
    result = num_check(guess, num)

elif result == 'low':

    guess = int(input('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
    att += 1
    result = num_check(guess, num)

else:

    print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), make sure your code is formatted exactly as you actually have it, and then *ask a question*, in the question itself (not just the title). Make sure your question is *direct* (not "does anyone know why?", but just "why ... ?") and *specific* (what do you mean by "a second attempt"? Where in the code are you expecting that attempt to happen? What should happen as a result? What does happen instead?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because python programs runs from top to bottom, and when it reaches the bottom it's done and stops running. To stop this order we have multiple different ways:

We can call a function, as you do in you're program.

Selection Control Structures: As if statements

Iteration Control Structures: As loops

The last one is the one you need in this solution. Wrap code in a while loop, with the correct condition, in you're example, this would be

```
# Input - Guess
guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))

att = 1

# Process - Guess and Display Result
result = num_check(guess, num)

if result == 'high':

    guess = int(input('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
    att += 1
    result = num_check(guess, num)

elif result == 'low':

    guess = int(input('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
    att += 1
    result = num_check(guess, num)

else:

    print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
```

The best way woul be to use a will loop as follow:

```
while guess != num:
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. When you explained top to bottom I got it. I was thinking after I ran the guess_check again the program would start back after the first guess_check call. It started back at the end of the if statement. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After getting input from console, you should create a loop which breaks when guessed number equal to input. For example:

```py
# Input - Guess
guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))

att = 1


# Process - Guess and Display Result
result = num_check(guess, num)

while result != guess:

    if result == 'high':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)

    elif result == 'low':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)
        
    else:
        break
    
print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
```

After revision, code seems like:

```py
import random

# Define function - Number Generator
def num_gen():

    num = random.randrange(1, 101)
    return num

# Define function - Number Check
def num_check(x, y):

    result = ''
    if x > y:
        result = 'high'
    elif x < y:
        result = 'low'
    else:
        result = 'correct'
    return result

# Call - Number Generator
num = num_gen()

# Input - Guess
guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))

att = 1


# Process - Guess and Display Result
result = num_check(guess, num)

while result != guess:

    if result == 'high':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)

    elif result == 'low':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)
        
    else:
        break
    
print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `while True:`, because your guessing code runs only once without it

```
import random

# Define function - Number Generator
def num_gen():

    num = random.randrange(1, 10)
    return num

# Define function - Number Check
def num_check(x, y):

    result = ''
    if x > y:
        result = 'high'
    elif x < y:
        result = 'low'
    else:
        result = 'correct'
    return result

# Call - Number Generator
att = 1
num = num_gen()
while True:
    # Input - Guess
    guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))
    # Process - Guess and Display Result
    result = num_check(guess, num)

    if result == 'high':
        print('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: ')
        att += 1

    elif result == 'low':
        print('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: ')
        att += 1

    else:
        print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

how can you expect it to run more than 1 time if you have not used any loop in the program. For example in this case you should use a `while loop`, then only it will prompt the user again and again and will check for the conditions, set a `game` variable to be `True`. When the number is matched then simply set the game variable to be `False` and it will end the loop.

```
import random

# Set the game variable initially to be True
game = True

# Define function - Number Generator
def num_gen():

    num = random.randrange(1, 101)
    return num

# Define function - Number Check
def num_check(x, y):

    result = ''
    if x > y:
        result = 'high'
    elif x < y:
        result = 'low'
    else:
        result = 'correct'
    return result

# Call - Number Generator
num = num_gen()

# Input - Guess
guess = int(input('Please guess a number between 1 and 100: '))

att = 1

# Process - Guess and Display Result
result = num_check(guess, num)

while game:

    if result == 'high':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was HIGH! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)

    elif result == 'low':

        guess = int(input('Your guess was LOW! Please guess another number between 1 and 100: '))
        att += 1
        result = num_check(guess, num)

    else:

        print('Your guess was CORRECT! You got it in ' + str(att) + ' attempts!')
        game = False
```